# Matlab - equation solve

Tags: matlab

Welcome ! I have a problem I want to solve in matlab this equation:

```
[(1,78e14 + 9,76^11)/128e6] +5e-5
```

Problem is that i'm getting error and i don't know how to type it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your [] to () because its interpreted as vector, also change the ',' to '.':

```
>> ((1.78e14 + 9.76^11)/128e6) +5e-5
ans =    1.3912e+06
```